# Ubuntu 14.04 Server HVM with EBS Free Tier AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm looking through the AWS Marketplace and Community AMI's to launch an instance on my newly registered free tier on Amazon. I'm very confused by the advertising of what's included in the free tier vs what offered in the AMI store.

For instance:

- The AWS documentation and store seem selling the **t2.micro** instances for the free tier (t1.micro is the "older-generation" and is grayed out)
- The **t2.micro** instance only supports **HVM** virtualization
- Under "Quick Start" for Launching an Instance, if I choose "Free Tier only" there's only one Ubuntu option: 14.04 LTS with **PV** virtualization ... not compatible with the **t2.micro** instace type.
- I found other instances on Ubuntu's [AMI locator](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/). When I follow the link, I am able to selct **t2.micro** and it says "free tier" (I'm guessing for the instance type, not the OS). But when I search for the AMI by its ID (e.g. ami-09b4b74c), it says nothing about the free tier.

I feel like I'm crazy, going in circles. Do the community AMI's qualify for the free tier? I've seen conflicting info about it. Say they don't. Why would the only free tier eligible Ubuntu image not be compatible with the only instance type I can get on the free tier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

t2.micro instances can only be HVM, while older t1.micro instances can only be PV. Whichever the AMI supports dictates which instance types will be available.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But that doesn't sort out any of the confusion about the free tier stuff. The free tier instance only supports HVM, but the free tier AMIs (linux) are only built for PV. See the problem?

Comment: The _old_ ones are. You'll have to wait for _new_ ones to be built, or build/convert your own AMIs.

Comment: How to can I find AMIS t2.micro type? Here is not clear the information https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html

Answer (score 1):

See http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ to find the correct Ubuntu image for your region.  For t2.micro, scroll to the bottom of the table, **select your region, HVM, and EBS.**

The Ubuntu 14.04 LTS HVM EBS AMI ID for us-east-1 as of today is: ami-9aaa1cf2

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu HVM AMIs are out now, it is ami-0307d674 and they are marked as free tier.